# Get and transfer data using an API

Tags: python, django, api

I have to develop an **API** to manage data between my **Database in PostGreSQL and my website in Django**.

I'm actually looking for the **best way** to manage and transfer this data, what I actually found on different topics / sites is the **Django Rest Framework to develop a Rest API in Django**, here I would use a JavaScript framework for the front like **React, Angular or VueJS** (any tips about which one to choose ? ).

I was wondering if there was other solutions that would be interesting ? I've been searching about **FTP** or things like this.

Thanks,

Comment: by "manage data" what kind of data are you talking about?

Comment: Informations about clients (name, contact, login ... ), the offer they chose to subscribe to ...

Comment: OK then You don't have to think about FTP. That's something else. Unrelated to your requirement

Comment: Use DRF or GraphQL. Because you are not only submitting information to the DB. You'll also retrieve information from your database.

Comment: Thank you, I'' have a look at GraphQL

Comment: I'll put that in the answer so you can close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas

Like you said you need to send and retrieve information like `name`, `contact`, `login detail` etc related to user and their subscriptions.

In this case you don't have to think about FTP. It isn't related here. FTP is something that you'll use to transfer files without django.

With django you will have to use `DRF` ([django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)) or use GraphQL along.
There is a package well known to use GraphQl called [graphene](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django)

For front end part you can use anything according to your requirement and skillset.

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the informations and the explanation I'll check GraphSQL and it's package graphene. Have a good day